# Using scss with ionic

Tags: ionic2

I am new to the ionic framework.I had written the code in scss and it is showing some bugs, I had tried to overcome the bugs but i can't.
Below is my scss code:

```
      //colors
       $grey: grey;
      //fonts
      $font_0: Arial;
      $font_1: Helvetica;
      $font_2: sans-serif;
 page-home 
{
 .displayed: ;
}
   .thicker {
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: $font_0, $font_1, $font_2;
   font-weight: 600;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 5px;
     }
 .input-label {
 font-family: $font_0, $font_1, $font_2;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: center;
 text-color: $grey;
 }
```

Is there anyone to help me!!!!

Comment: when i am running the app it is showing errors

Answer (score 1):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/

You should set the SCSS variables in the theme/variable.scss file when you require global access. All your individual scss files can use it.

```
    page-home  {}
```

"page-home" is your scss namespace for your pageHome.html. It is specified in  your component(ts file). All css for that file should be within the namespace.

SCSS tutorial link: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: I coudl be more specific if I know what the bug is :)

Comment: I nearly agree, I'd rather say : "It is **required** to set the SCSS variables in the theme/variable.scss file **when you want** global access." Because there are many cases when it is better to set a local SCSS variable only in the one SCSS file that uses it.

Comment: would have figured out the compilation error.But not really in a position to compile :)

Comment: I usually call this "mental compilation" ;).

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your SCSS :

```
page-home 
{
    .displayed: ;
}
```

This will not compile and will throw this error :

```
Invalid CSS after "{": expected "}", was ".displayed: ;"
```

When I switch it to :

```
page-home 
{
}
```

Then it compiles.